# Magento2 Error Message not shown after redirection to another Page

Tags: magento2, messages

Magento2 I need to redirect to Home page & display error msg after clicking button in product detail page.
I have written below code in my custom controller file but msg doesn't print on Home page instead it is displayed on same page for few seconds and then it gets redirect to home page

```
$this->messageManager->addError(__("Message"));
header("Location: ".$pricing_url);
exit;
```

Let me know proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below code

```
public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Submitted Successfully.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('review/customer/review');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```

Comment: What if I am using header("Location: ".$home_url);  for redirecting page will it create difference ?

Comment: $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account');
return $resultRedirect;

Comment: You mean to say it is compulsory to use $resultRedirect for message manager ?

Comment: yes use $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account'); return $resultRedirect;

Comment: Was facing issue with $this->_redirect and got it solved by using this instead

$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Could not find any records. Please try again!'));
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

                return $resultRedirect;